# question about modifying a pointer using another pointer in a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about the following code. I am not sure why the address stored in yAdd doesn't get updated to the same address stored in the variable x inside the addfun() function in the code below? what is wrong with my thinking?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(int *x) {
    *x = 55;
}

void addfun(int **x) {
    *x = new int[3];
    cout << x << endl;  // x stores the address of int[0]
                        // say it is 0x7ffc32e646a0
    cout << &x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 99;
    int *yAdd = &y;
    cout << y << endl;
    fun(yAdd);
    cout << y   << endl;
    cout << yAdd << endl; // original address stored in yAdd
    cout << "address of y is " << &y <<  endl;
    addfun(&yAdd);   // so I update the address stored in yAdd to be the same address
                    // as stored inside the x in the addfun function
    cout << yAdd << endl; // but how come when printing this, yAdd doesn't 
                    // show 0x7ffc32e646a0, but something else?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
addfun(&yAdd);
```

This is passing the address of `yAdd` to this function, as a parameter.

`yAdd` is a pointer. The pointer is an address of some other object in your program. It doesn't matter what that object is, yAdd is its pointer, and whatever `yAdd` itself, its address gets passed.

```
cout << yAdd << endl;
```

This shows the value of `yAdd`.  Whatever this pointer is, its value is shown. And the address of this object, of `yAdd`, is something completely different.

```
void addfun(int **x)
```

`x` is a parameter to this function. `x` is a variable, that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with any other variable in your program. As such, it will have its own memory address, different than the memory address of everything else in your program (at least while it exists).

```
cout << &x << endl;
```

And this shows `x`'s address. It is not showing the value of `yAdd`. It is not showing `yAdd`s address, either. It is showing the address of `x`, a parameter to this function.

All of these are separate, distinct, objects and values in your program.

Comment: oh I don't mean cout << x  << endl; should show address of yAdd. I mean when I put the address of yAdd into the addfun function, should that function not modify what pointed to by yAdd? So shouldn't yAdd now pointed to the same place as pointed to by the x variable inside the addfun function? i.e. shouldn't they point the same place? i.e. yAdd == x ?

Comment: No it's not. `x` is a parameter to `addfun()`. When `x` returns, it gets destroyed. It ceases to exist. It starts pining for the fjords. It is no more. It is an ex object. `yAdd` is not `x`. `yAdd` is what `*x` ***used to be***. `yadd()` does not set `x`. It literally sets `*x`. `yAdd` set `*x`. It does not sets `x`. That's what its code literally says. Printing what `x` is, or what it's address is, has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with what `*x` is.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to print out some more and label it better:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(int *x) {
    *x = 55;
}

void addfun(int **x) {
    cout << endl << "addfun()" << endl;
    cout << "x  = " <<  x << endl;
    cout << "*x = " << *x << endl;
    cout << "new int[3]" << endl;
    *x = new int[3];
    cout << "x  = " <<  x << endl;
    cout << "*x = " << *x << endl;
    cout << "addfun() done" << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 99;
    int *yAdd = &y;
    cout << y << endl;
    fun(yAdd);
    cout << y   << endl;
    cout << "&yAdd = " << &yAdd << endl;
    cout << "yAdd  = " << yAdd << endl;
    cout << "*yAdd = " << *yAdd << endl;
    cout << "address of y is " << &y <<  endl;
    addfun(&yAdd);   // so I update the address stored in yAdd to be the same address
                    // as stored inside the x in the addfun function
    cout << "&yAdd = " << &yAdd << endl;
    cout << "yAdd  = " << yAdd << endl;
    cout << "*yAdd = " << *yAdd << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This produces for example the following output:

```
99
55
&yAdd = 0x7ffc9e47fe58
yAdd  = 0x7ffc9e47fe54
*yAdd = 55
address of y is 0x7ffc9e47fe54

addfun()
x  = 0x7ffc9e47fe58
*x = 0x7ffc9e47fe54
new int[3]
x  = 0x7ffc9e47fe58
*x = 0x564ab462d2c0
addfun() done

&yAdd = 0x7ffc9e47fe58
yAdd  = 0x564ab462d2c0
*yAdd = 0
```

As you can see when you enter `addfun` the value of x is the address of `yAdd` which points to `y`. Then you allocate the `int[3]` and assign the result to `*x`. That is you store the address of `int[3]` into where `x` points to, namely `yAdd`. The value of `x` is not changed.

After the call to `addfun` you can see that the address of `yAdd` is still the same as and the same as `x` was but where `yAdd` points to has now been changed to `int[3]`.

I think the bit where you got confused is `*x = ...`. That changes the things `x` points at and not `x` itself.

Comment: Oh, I think I know where my confusion is now. Thanks. But I am just wondering so now yAdd points to the array of size of 3 integers. So is there anyway I can use yAdd to put some elements into the 3 positions of that array I allocated? like can I do yAdd[0] = 987, yAdd[1]= 75, yAdd[2] = -13 ? like can I treat yAdd as an array and use the above notation to assign values into the specific positions? and similarly can I use *yAdd = 987, *(yAdd + 1) = 75, *(yAdd + 2) = -13?

Answer (score 0):

Within the function `addfun`

```
void addfun(int **x) {
    *x = new int[3];
    cout << x << endl;  // x stores the address of int[0]
                        // say it is 0x7ffc32e646a0
    cout << &x << endl;
}
```

the statement

```
    cout << x << endl;  // x stores the address of int[0]
                        // say it is 0x7ffc32e646a0
```

prints the address of the original pointer `yAdd` passed to the function

```
addfun(&yAdd);
```

In main this statement

```
cout << yAdd << endl;
```

outputs the value assigned to the pointer within the function `addfun` in this statement

```
    *x = new int[3];
```

that is the address of the dynamically allocated memory.

The assigned value to the pointer `yAdd` and the address of the pointer itself are two different values.

Comment: But shouldn't yAdd now stores the same address as what x storing now?  i.e. these two pointers both point to the same place in memory?

Comment: No, x points to yAdd and you store the allocated array into where x points to.